# How to convert dates range into string in swift 3?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, calendar

How Can I convert dates into string format?

I am getting dates between two dates ( From to end date). and I was using this below method

```
class Dates {
static func printDatesBetweenInterval(_ startDate: Date, _ endDate: Date) {
    var startDate = startDate
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let fmt = DateFormatter()
    fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    while startDate <= endDate {
        print(fmt.string(from: startDate))
        startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate)!
    }
}

static func dateFromString(_ dateString: String) -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
}}
```

and printing dates here

```
Dates.printDatesBetweenInterval(Dates.dateFromString("2017-10-02"), Dates.dateFromString("2017-10-9"))
```

result:

```
2017-10-02 2017-10-03 2017-10-04 2017-10-05 2017-10-06 2017-10-07 2017-10-08 2017-10-09
```

Now, I want pass this dates to String format to calendar (I am using FSCalendar lib into app). I want this format
example:

```
["2017-10-02", "2017-10-03", "2017-10-04", "2017-10-05", "2017-10-06", "2017-10-07", "2017-10-08", "2017-10-09"]
```

Can anyone guide me . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Return date string array from your function, like this:

```
class Dates {
static func printDatesBetweenInterval(_ startDate: Date, _ endDate: Date) -> [String] {
    var startDate = startDate
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let fmt = DateFormatter()
    fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    var arrayDateString = [String]()

    while startDate <= endDate {
        let stringDate = fmt.string(from: startDate)
        print("stringDate - \(stringDate)")
        arrayDateString.append(stringDate)
        startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate)!
    }

   return arrayDateString
}

static func dateFromString(_ dateString: String) -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
}}
```

Now, print string array

```
let dateStringArray = Dates.printDatesBetweenInterval(Dates.dateFromString("2017-10-02"), Dates.dateFromString("2017-10-9"))

print("dateStringArray - \(dateStringArray)")
```

**Edit:**

Now, as you said, you've data in following format:

```
let dataArray = [ 
 { "hlddate": "07-Aug", "frmdt": "07-Aug-2017", "todt": "07-Aug-2017" }, 
 { "hlddate": "15-Aug", "frmdt": "15-Aug-2017", "todt": "15-Aug-2017" }, 
 { "hlddate": "10-Oct", "frmdt": "10-Oct-2017","todt": "31-Oct-2017" } 
]
```

Try with following solution (Copy-paste, dataAray and class structure and see result):

```
class Dates {

static func dateFromString(dateString: String, webResponseDateFormat: String = "yyyy-MM-dd") -> Date? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = webResponseDateFormat
    return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
 }}

 static func printDatesBetweenInterval(startDate: Date, endDate: Date, requiredDateFormat: String = "yyyy-MM-dd") -> [String] {
    var startDate = startDate
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let fmt = DateFormatter()
    fmt.dateFormat = requiredDateFormat

    var arrayDateString = [String]()

    while startDate <= endDate {
        let stringDate = fmt.string(from: startDate)
        print("stringDate - \(stringDate)")
        arrayDateString.append(stringDate)
        startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate)!
    }

   return arrayDateString
 }


if let stringDateArray = dataArray as? [[String : String]] {

   for arrayElement in stringDateArray {

       if let startDateString = arrayElement["frmdt"], let startDate = Dates.dateFromString(dateString: startDateString, webResponseDateFormat: "dd-MMM-yyyy"), let endDateString = arrayElement["todt"], let endDate = Dates.dateFromString(dateString: endDateString, webResponseDateFormat: "dd-MMM-yyyy") {

           let dateStringArray = Dates.printDatesBetweenInterval(startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate, )

           print("\n\n**\ndateStringArray - \(dateStringArray)")
       }
   }

}
```

**Final Update**

```
// Actual data structure
let dataArray = ["07-8-2017","08-08-2017","10-09-2017","20-10-2017",21-10-2017","23-10-2017", etc..]
```

Use above method and change data in server response section and getting result.

```
if let Streams = jsonDict["data"] as! [AnyObject]? {

   for arrayElement in Streams {

        if let startDateString = arrayElement["frmdt"] {
             self.somedateFromString = self.convertStringToDate(string: startDateString as! String)

            if  let endDateString = arrayElement["todt"] {
                self.somedateEndString = self.convertStringToDate(string: endDateString as! String)
            }

   self.presentdays = Dates.printDatesBetweenInterval(Dates.dateFromString(self.somedateFromString), Dates.dateFromString(self.somedateEndString))

        self.totalHolidays.append(contentsOf: self.presentdays)

     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! This is working fine , but  ''"data": [ { "hlddate": "07-Aug", "frmdt": "07-Aug-2017", "todt": "07-Aug-2017" }, { "hlddate": "15-Aug", "frmdt": "15-Aug-2017", "todt": "15-Aug-2017" }, { "hlddate": "10-Oct", "frmdt": "10-Oct-2017","todt": "31-Oct-2017" } ]' ' This is i am getting response from server. and how can i pass single array to calendar  and please guide me.

Comment: 'let dataArray = [ 
 { "hlddate": "07-Aug", "frmdt": "07-Aug-2017", "todt": "07-Aug-2017" }, 
 { "hlddate": "15-Aug", "frmdt": "15-Aug-2017", "todt": "15-Aug-2017" }, 
 { "hlddate": "10-Oct", "frmdt": "10-Oct-2017","todt": "31-Oct-2017" } 
] '.  No, I need to take one array of ALL dates as like this format. Ex:--     ' let dataArray =["07-08-2017", "15-08-2017, "10-10-2017", "11-10-2017", "12-10-2017", "13-10-2017", -------- , "30-10-2017", "31-10-2017"]

Comment: I did your updated answer, i was getting last array of data into Dictionary ex: '["2017-10-10", "2017-10-11", "2017-10-12", "2017-10-13", "2017-10-14", "2017-10-15", "2017-10-16", "2017-10-17", "2017-10-18", "2017-10-19", "2017-10-20", "2017-10-21", "2017-10-22", "2017-10-23", "2017-10-24", "2017-10-25", "2017-10-26", "2017-10-27", "2017-10-28", "2017-10-29", "2017-10-30", "2017-10-31"]'  . I am not added into first and second array in it. but i printed first & second array dates.  please guide me

Comment: Ok, give me some time, will provide exact solution with result.

Comment: Thanks !. No issues, take your time , send me solution if you find out. and also i am trying to solve problem from my side.

Comment: Thanks for supporting me. I resolved my issues finally. solution is clear. I was append dates using for loop. after that [] array passed into calendar. Thanks again

Comment: Nice, can you add the same solution, by updating this answer. You solution will add importance to this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
static func getDatesStringBetweenInterval(_ startDate: Date, _ endDate: Date)-> String {
        var retval = "["

        var startDate = startDate
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        let fmt = DateFormatter()
        fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

        while startDate <= endDate {
            if startDate < endDate {
                retval.append("\"\(fmt.string(from: startDate))\", ")
            } else {
               retval.append("\"\(fmt.string(from: startDate))\"")
            }
            startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate)!
        }
        retval.append("]")

        return retval
    }
```

Usage:

```
let aDate = Dates.dateFromString("2017-01-01")
let bDate = Dates.dateFromString("2017-01-05")
let datesString = Dates.getDatesStringBetweenInterval(aDate, bDate)
print(datesString)
```

Comment: OP needs an array of date strings

Comment: "Now, I want pass this dates to String format" <- Means that OP needs this date in string format @LeoDabus

Comment: `["2017-10-02", "2017-10-03", "2017-10-04", "2017-10-05", "2017-10-06", "2017-10-07", "2017-10-08", "2017-10-09"]` doesn't look like a single string

Comment: @losDeveloper, please specify which format you need exactly.

Comment: no api would need a string with a bunch of dates separated by a comma

Comment: @LeoDabus, I'm agree with you that this doesn't look like a single string, but my answer is based on the question. Maybe there is some mistake...

Comment: @Dmitry Sorry for late reply, I was bit busy with New project.  Usually I am getting response from server below type:  '"data": [  { "hlddate": "07-Aug", "frmdt": "07-Aug-2017", "todt": "07-Aug-2017" }, {  "hlddate": "15-Aug",  "frmdt": "15-Aug-2017", "todt": "15-Aug-2017"  }, {  "hlddate": "10-Oct", "frmdt": "10-Oct-2017","todt": "31-Oct-2017" } ]' Then I want to pass string format above type  to FSCalendar. Thanks